# C# WebApi how can I obfuscate js which can still be readen in client console

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I programmed a web api service which return a js code to client,

I want to keep my code safe from copy (if can),
I saw on this website [online obfuscator](https://javascriptobfuscator.com/Javascript-Obfuscator.aspx) an obfuscator which scramble the string code and keeps it readable by console

alert('Hello') converted to var _0x85a4=["\x48\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F"];alert(_0x85a4[0])

the converted line will pop up "Hello" alert in console.

is there a way in c# to convert a string the same way and keeps it readable by the client console?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question I have to say. The short answer is not really with just C# even if there was an obfuscator for c# it probably would not be any god. 
**BUT** asp.net core (might work on the old stack as well I am not sure 100% sure) to the rescue. In the new stack there is something called [NodeServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices#microsoftaspnetcorenodeservices) this is what they use for server side pre rendering it requires node.js to do the work but this is how you will get what you want.

Here is a quick sample (you should optimize a lot more in a real app) on how to do it. I used javascript-obfuscator to do the scrambling but you can use any one you like. 
The C# code

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddNodeServices();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                INodeServices nodeServices = context.RequestServices.GetService<INodeServices>();

                var inputJS = @"(function(){
                                    var variable1 = '5' - 3;
                                    var variable2 = '5' + 3;
                                    var variable3 = '5' + - '2';
                                    console.log(variable1);
                                    console.log(variable2);
                                    console.log(variable3);
                                })();";

                try
                {
                    var result = await nodeServices.InvokeAsync<string>("./obfuscate", inputJS);

                    context.Response.ContentType = "application/javascript";

                    context.Response.StatusCode = 200;

                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                    throw;
                }

            });
        }
    }
```

And the javascript I put in in root and named it obfuscate.js

```
var JavaScriptObfuscator = require('javascript-obfuscator')
module.exports = function (callback, text) {

    var obfuscationResult = JavaScriptObfuscator.obfuscate(
        text,
        {
            compact: false,
            controlFlowFlattening: true,
            disableConsoleOutput: false
        }
    );


    callback(null, obfuscationResult.getObfuscatedCode());
};
```

Remember you need to have node.js installed on the machine running the server and the files on the machine.